# Linux shell command to read text file and open documents listed within

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

I have written a shell script (bin/bash). The script takes a look inside folders startup, source and objects that are all located in current folder. Then it makes lists (text files) named **startup_list** (includes files with extension .s), **sources_list** (files with extension .c) and **objects_list** (includes files with extension .o). We asign all .s files to variable ASFILE, all .c files to GCCFILE and all .o to LDFILE.

```
ASDIR="$(pwd)/startup"
GCCDIR="$(pwd)/source"
LDDIR="$(pwd)/objects"
INCDIR="$(pwd)/include"

ls $ASDIR/*.s > startup_list
sed -i 's|..*/||g' startup_list
ASFILE=$(cat startup_list)

ls $GCCDIR/*.c > sources_list
sed -i 's|..*/||g' sources_list
GCCFILE=$(cat sources_list)

cat startup_list sources_list > objects_list
sed -e 's/\.c/\.o/g' objects_list > objects_list_tmp
sed -e 's/\.s/\.o/g' objects_list_tmp > objects_list
LDFILE=$(cat objects_list)
```

This script will be integrated into a **makefile** later, but i now need a shell comand to open .c files one after another and check what are the dependancies listed behind #include command. One more thing. Text documents startup_list, sources_list and object_list have files listed one in each line. It looks like this:

```
ea3131_startup_entry.c
pad.c
ea3131_board.c
lpc313x_cgu_default.c
lpc313x_cgu_driver.c
lpc313x_dma_driver.c
lpc313x_evt_driver.c
```

If I omit commands

```
sed -i 's|..*/||g' sources_list 
sed -i 's|..*/||g' startup_list
```

I can also get an absolute path to the file in front of it, so the text files look like this:

```
/home/ziga/Dropbox/diploma/86x_linux/IDE_eclipse/eclipse_projects/LPC3141_SHELL_timer_makefile/startup/ea3131_startup_entry.c
/home/ziga/Dropbox/diploma/86x_linux/IDE_eclipse/eclipse_projects/LPC3141_SHELL_timer_makefile/startup/pad.c
/home/ziga/Dropbox/diploma/86x_linux/IDE_eclipse/eclipse_projects/LPC3141_SHELL_timer_makefile/source/ea3131_board.c
/home/ziga/Dropbox/diploma/86x_linux/IDE_eclipse/eclipse_projects/LPC3141_SHELL_timer_makefile/source/lpc313x_cgu_default.c
/home/ziga/Dropbox/diploma/86x_linux/IDE_eclipse/eclipse_projects/LPC3141_SHELL_timer_makefile/source/lpc313x_cgu_driver.c
```

So what are my options here? How can i open these .c files and check what i need to check?

Regards Ziga

---

Here is my full makefile I did write taking your advices. It is not finished yet. I still need to add lines that compile *.c files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# najprej nastavimo shell, ki je v nasem primeru bash

# nastavitev asemblerja, compilerja in linkerja
AS="arm-none-eabi-as"
GCC="arm-none-eabi-gcc"
LD="arm-none-eabi-ld"

# nastavitev nastavitev za asembler, compiler in linker
ASOPT="-mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall"
GCCOPT="-mcpu=arm926ej-s -c -Wall"
LDOPT="-Tldscript_iram_gnu.ld"

# nastavitev direktorij v katerih se nahajajo kljucne datoteke za sestavo programa
ASDIR="$(pwd)/startup"
GCCDIR="$(pwd)/source"
LDDIR="$(pwd)/objects"
INCDIR="$(pwd)/include"

# potrebno je locirati vse startup, source in objektne datoteke. Ker objektnih datotek še ni, jih je potrebno sproti narediti in jih vse premakniti v mapo objects
ls $ASDIR/*.s > startup_list
sed -i 's|..*/||g' startup_list
ASFILE=$(cat startup_list)

ls $GCCDIR/*.c > sources_list
sed -i 's|..*/||g' sources_list 
GCCFILE=$(cat sources_list)

cat startup_list sources_list > objects_list
sed -e 's/\.c/\.o/g' objects_list > objects_list_tmp
sed -e 's/\.s/\.o/g' objects_list_tmp > objects_list
LDFILE=$(cat objects_list)

all: executable

executable: $(LDFILE)
    $(GCC) -M $(LDFILE)

clean: 
    rm startup_list sources_list objects_list objects_list_tmp
    echo Pocistili ste vse datoteke.
```

For some reason when i run "make" or "make clean" command i get an error:

```
makefile:21: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong but i think i dont quite understand how to properly use bash comands within makefile, especially variables. Sometimes i use them as $(BOO) and sometimes as $BOO. First one works in a makefile but fails in a command line interface, whereas second works opposite. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You know `-M` flag of `gcc`? (There are several options all starting with -M where you can define where to write which dependencies - this invocation is independent from later compilation, no code/object files will be generated is just parsing of the deps)

Comment: This looks VERY usefull and my script is partly unnecesary... I will take a look in -M flag and then return back here in case i encounter any problems.

Comment: So this way i can use command "arm-none-eabi-gcc -W $LDFILE" (LDFILE is a variable that holds objects_list). I then get makefile dependancies for all object files. Now i only need to put comands to compile (arm-none-eabi-gcc -c) the objects between these dependancies. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Hello, i ve looked into it and managed to create dependancy list for .c files, but how can i create dependancy list for .s (assembly) files? Using -M option always leaves me an empty output.